# Destructing rvalue references

Tags: c++, c++11, destructor, rvalue-reference

I'm trying to learn how to use rvalue references. Can anyone explain why the following code works? Why isn't the `D` that is sent from `B`'s initialization list to `A`'s constructor not destructed when the `B`'s constructor goes out of scope?

```
class C {
public:
     void test() {
          std::cout << i << " ok!\n";
     }
private:
    int i = rand();
};
class D: public C {};

class A {
public:
     A(C &&c) : m_c(c) {}
     void test() {m_c.test();}
private:
     C &m_c;
};

class B: public A {
public:
     B() : A(D()) {}
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
     A *a = new B();
     a->test();
}
```

Comment: I think it _is_, isn't it? Looks like UB to me.

Comment: My guess is that if you used *stateful* information in ``D``/``C``, this wouldn't work. The way I'd read it it's essentially getting a reference to the function table of ``C``, and can call its methods. It's just the implicit ``this`` in any of ``C``'s methods would be invalid. Basically, ``test()`` is following the requirements of a ``static`` method without actually being declared ``static``. It's totally UB to do this, but it happens to work in this case.

Comment: R-value references are still references.  If an l-value reference would refer to a dangling object, then an r-value reference to the same would also refer to a dangling object.

Comment: One explanation could be if you're using MSVC as it allows non const references to temporaries by extension. Who knows what else they do to make it work or for how long they extend the lifetime of the object... :s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The temporary `D` is being destructed, and you have undefined behavior by calling a method of an object whose lifetime has ended.

When you have undefined behavior, working just fine is one possible behavior.

Comment: You're probably right that it's undefined behavior. However, I updated my example to access this, and it still seems to be working.

Comment: @MagnarMyrtveit: Yes, even accessing a member of an object whose lifetime has ended doesn't guarantee a crash.

Comment: Valid undefined behaviour includes: beaming kittens into space, launching ze missiles, turning all the milk in your fridge sour ... or appearing to "work".